# Запятая в перечислении действий в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "и указывается" в следующем предложении?

> Пишется ключевое слово lambda, затем указывается один или несколько аргументов, затем ставится двоеточие и указывается возвращаемое значение.

UPD: всем большое спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нет, здесь запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

*Ставится* и *указывается* однородные члены при *затем,* поэтому запятая совсем **не нужна.**

Comment: Где тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (перед "однородные")? И в этом правиле не однородные члены фигурируют, а однородные простые предложения. Если строго (как правильно), то данные члены нельзя назвать однородными, потому что они связаны с разными подлежащими. Да и сам термин — "однородные члены [простого] предложения", не предложений. Они отвечают на один вопрос, который задаётся от другого члена предложения, для сказуемых таковым является подлежащее. У Розенталя говорится про "части".

Comment: А мне и без тире хорошо, не нравится оно мне тут совсем. Связаны с разными подлежащими?!

Comment: Конечно же, Артём, это  **части** сложносочиненного предложения, объединенные общим обстоятельством. Это два предложения: ***затем** ставится двоеточие **и** указывается значение*. Однородные члены обычно отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и связаны с **одним и тем же словом** в предложении.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: то есть, поскольку предложений два, это не однородные члены, да?

Answer (score 2):

> **2.** Перед союзами ***и**, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо **общим элементом**.
> **1)** Общим может быть второстепенный член предложения: ***Вскоре после восхода** набежала туча **и** брызнул короткий дождь* (П.)... ***В сенях** пахло свежими яблоками **и** висели волчьи и лисьи шкуры* (Л. Т.)...

Общий элемент — наречие [затем](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) (= потом, после), поэтому запятой перед союзом "и" нет.

*Параметры одного типа можно перечислять через запятую, **затем** ставится двоеточие **и** указывается их тип.

...из которой взята цитата, **затем** ставится двоеточие или запятая **и** указывается страница работы, на которой расположено цитируемое суждение.*

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)